# How to put an integer in a individual number by arry?

Tags: c

I want to input an integer such as 123454321.  Then I want to print it in
this form:1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

  int A[100];
  int i, input, current;
  printf("Input n:");
  scanf("%d",&input);
  printf("\n");

  for(i=1; i!=0; i++){
    A[i]=input%10;
    input=input/10;
    printf("%d ",A[i]);
    current++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So.. what is the problem?

Comment: `for(i=1; i!=0; i++)` - that's a weird loop. Do you think it will terminate?

Comment: you just want to print it or stock it inside an array and after print what's inside the array ?

Comment: The example value you used is not the best, since it's a palindrome (reads the same backwards as forwards) - ie. it won't let you find out if you print the digits in the wrong order. I suggest using a different value to test with.

Comment: When `current++;` is first executed, `current` does not have a prior defined value.  It is not used here, so might as well drop it.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your input into your array like you do and display it, but the input will be reverse.

In case of intput: 12345

Value will be stored like this: `A[0] = 5, A[1] = 4, ...`

To change that you will have to display `A[]` from the end to the start. (already answered by chux)

Or you can store your input into `A[]` from the end to the start and after simply display it:

Example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              

int main(void)                                                                  
{                                                                                                                                                           
    int A[100];                                                                   
    int i, input, len, nb;                                                        
    printf("Input n:");                                                           
    scanf("%d",&input);                                                           
    printf("\n");                                                                 

    nb = input;           //I do a save of input.                                 

    for(len = 0; nb != 0; len++){ //Calculating the size of the input             
      nb = nb / 10;               //                                              
    }                             //                                              
    len--;
    for(int z = len; input != 0; z--){ //I copy the input into A.                 
      A[z] = input % 10;               //                                         
      input = input / 10;              //                                         
    }                                                                             

    for(i = 0; i <= len; i++) // I display A                                      
      printf("%d ",A[i]);     //                                                  

    return 0;                                                                     
}
```

**EDIT:**

By the way your for:

```
for(i=1; i!=0; i++){
    A[i]=input%10;
    input=input/10;
    printf("%d ",A[i]);
    current++;
}
```

Will infinite loop because `i` is never equals to 0 and the case `A[0]` of your array will not be used because `ì` start at `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the values for `A[]` looping in one direction and then print the values in the other loop direction.

Let us assume `input >= 0`.
A `do` loop is useful here to handle the case of `input == 0` to print `"0"`.

```
i = 0;
do {
  A[i] = input%10;
  input = input/10;
  i++;
} while (input);
```

Now print looping the other way

```
while (i) {
  printf("%d ", A[--i]);
}
printf("\n");
```